# Is the sentence "something created using something else" good english?

Tags: grammaticality

I had s discussion with someone who told me the title of my thesis is incorrect in english. The title reads:

> Optimizing websites created using the Wordpress framework

Neither of us is native english so the discussion didn't really go anywhere but my reasoning is as follows:

The websites have been made inside the wordpress framework but the optimization only partially occurred within this framework. Therefor a sentence like:

> Optimizing websites using the Wordpress framework

would be incorrect in describing what the thesis is about.

Am I correct here? Is the first sentence correct english?

Comment: "Optimizing websites using the Wordpress framework" is ambiguous: it is uncertain whether the websites or the optimization use the Wordpress framework. "Optimizing websites created using the Wordpress framework" isn't ambiguous in the same way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IMO, your title is not grammatically incorrect.  Wordy, yes - incorrect, no.

May I suggest: "Optimizing Wordpress Websites"?

Or, if you want to keep with the academic style of titling theses (with many words), you could change it to: "Optimizing Websites Created ***in*** Wordpress Framework."